# MVC 5 HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden on Manager Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Under my MVC 5 project, I created "ManagerController" and tried to access via localhost/myapp/manager but it gives "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error.

If I create MyAppManagerController and try to access via localhost/myapp/MyAppManager there is no issue.

Is "Manager" is a reserved keyword in MVC world? Should I add extra configuration to create this controller?

Comment: No, `Manager` is not a reserved keyword. Check presence of `Authorize` attribute on your controller class or action method, remove it if any and test again by accessing `localhost/myapp/Manager/[actionname]`.

Comment: It is a plain simple controller, I already created controllers with Authorize attribute and works as expected. There is no any filter on this controller and only action is Index method which returns view. If I create plain simple another controller it works well.

Comment: In your case, ensure either you don't have an actual virtual/physical directory named "Manager", or use `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true` in `RouteConfig` (show all files to reveal excluded folders when checking). Also you may show `RouteConfig` contents if necessary.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto OMG, you are right. Someone created a business object class under "Manager" folder and it was preventing to being rendered. After I renamed that folder it works great. Thanks!